# My hibernate/jpql query returns duplicated values when there is join, how can I avoid it

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpql

I have jpql query which maps output of query to specific object

```
return em.createQuery(
        "SELECT DISTINCT new org.some.great.project.Statuses(u.accountStatus, COUNT(u.accountStatus)) "
            + "FROM XUser u LEFT JOIN u.products p "
            + "WHERE p.id IN :productIds "
            + "GROUP BY u.accountStatus", Statuses.class)
    .setParameter(PRODUCT_IDS, productIds) 
    .getResultList();
```

And everything is ok, until `XUser` does have only on relation to `Product` table.
If it has more than one, `count(xx)` will add additional record.

My mapping in `XUser` looks like following

```
public class XUser {

    //other

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "XUser_product",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "user_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
        ),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "product_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
        )
    )
    private Set<Product> products;

    //other
}
```

If I check logs hibernate (maps jpql to followin sql) is running query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ACCOUNTSTATUS, COUNT(t.ACCOUNTSTATUS) FROM XUser x, XUSER_PRODUCT xp , PRODUCT p
WHERE x.ID = xp.XUSER_ID
AND xp.PRODUCT_ID = p.ID
AND p.ID IN (some nubers)
GROUP BY t.ACCOUNTSTATUS;
```

So if I modify it a little, and instead of returning `count` with status, I want to return everything I am getting

| ID | NAME | ACCOUNTSTATUS | XUSER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | ID | NM | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | DEAD | 1 | 12 | 12 | test | 199 |
| 1 | Peter | DEAD | 1 | 123 | 123 | fruit | 999 |
| 2 | Tom | OK | 2 | 98 | 98 | tabasco | 11 |
| 3 | Kate | DEAD | 3 | 87 | 87 | mars | 2 |

So as you can see I have displayed `Peter` with `ID=1` two times. And If this query is changed to previous one I would see

```
DEAD: 3 // and I need to have here 2
OK  : 1
```

Any ideas, hints how to handle it?

Comment: What is the goal of your query, count how many dead accounts you have?

Comment: Not exactly, point of hibernate query is to return `List<Statuses>`, where one `Statuses` contain count of users with given status. So: `[0] -> DEAD: 3, [1] -> OK: 1` etc.

Comment: Then why do you bother about which products they have a relationship with?

Comment: `SELECT x.ACCOUNTSTATUS, COUNT(1) FROM XUser x GROUP BY x.ACCOUNTSTATUS`

Comment: If you want status for users that "bought" certain products: `SELECT x.ACCOUNTSTATUS, COUNT(1) FROM XUser x WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM XUSER_PRODUCT xp  JOIN PRODUCT p ON xp.PRODUCT_ID = p.ID WHERE p.ID IN (....) AND x.ID = xp.XUSER_ID)`

Comment: @Lennart 1. Because I am passing from frontend productId's. 2. I understnd that second query is working correctly, but I was asking about hibernate/jpql, the last part was just put here because I did checked what query was executed.